# RecyclerView item connected with vertical line

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView`. In some cases I need to connect two `items vertically` to show the connection between them like in the image below:

[image]

The only thing I'm thinking about is to create another `ViewHolder` which will look like it was connected but this option will limit me in case I will need to connect three or more items and will have to create a `ViewHolder` for each case.
Maybe someone has a better idea of how to achieve this goal?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not the use background drawable the gives the illusion that they are connected. Like one drawable will have border and small opening at bottom and one will have small opening at tap. For multiple connection , a drawable with small opening at both top and bottom. Same can be achieved using ViewHolder, 3 viewholders , similar concept as drawable , just giving the illusion it's connected but not actually connected.

Comment: @Nitish 
It's a good idea, but how I'm going to draw the vertical orange lines like in the example?

Comment: For that part I didn't think through, we can try searching and try to create a drawable. As of now I have no idea. But as a last option we can always use svg image as a backgroumd.

Comment: I think it should be doable with [ItemDecorations](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration) I think, making the connection a sort of divider, using `onDrawOver` but unfortunately I don't have any experience with it myself so I can't help you with that

Comment: @IvoBeckers I was thinking about this also, but have no idea how do I make the Divider above the ViewHolder and make it with elevation.

Answer (score 1):

Use three Viewtypes.

1 Background Drawable with the space at the bottom
2. Drawable with 2 vertical lines
3  Background Drawable with the space at the top

Make sure there's no margin between the three recyclerview items with the different viewtypes